# Looking for a drasha on Yerach ben Yomo/Karnei Para

Tags: midrash, trop-cantillation, masei

Anyone have any links to any drashos explaining the significance of the Yerach ben Yomo/Karnei Para trop, and why it appears (uniquely in chumash) in the portion about the Levite cities ([Numbers 35:5](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0435.htm#5))?

Comment: It also appears in other places.

Comment: @DoubleAA Another rare trop, shalsheles, appears only 4 times in chumash.  Each time there is a drasha on the word, indicating the the person in question had some kind of hesitation or dilemma.  I'm interested in the uniqueness of yby/kp, the fact that it appears only once in chumash, and in place it seems a pretty prosaic section.  Why davka here?  It does seem pretty significant, doesn't it?

Comment: Why didnt you say all that in the question??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a link [to a Drasha from Rabbi Moshe Wolfson Shlita](http://www.rambish.org.il/journals/n/nezer_hatora/vol018/nezer01845.pdf) on this topic.