# Unusual Notes in Tenach

Tags: trop-cantillation

Does anyone explain the meaning of the karnei para on Bemidbar 35:5 and Yehoshua 19:51.  I believe there are 16 of these in Tenach.  There are also meircha kefulahs in  Bereishis 27:25 and Bemidbar 32:42.
How do these notes help us understand the text?  No one I’ve spoken to can relate what Rav Kook writes on page 4 of the attachment with any of the examples above or the 4 shalshelets in Chumash.  If you can shed any light, that would be great.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43607/looking-for-a-drasha-on-yerach-ben-yomo-karnei-para http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43763/whats-special-about-where-the-unique-karne-farah-trope-appears (about the Karnei Parah)

Comment: Merkha Kefula is just what happens when a Tipcha has two Meshartim. If it has one, it gets a Merkha. If it has two, it gets Darga-MerkhaKefula. That's it. It never gets three and only gets two 14 times in Tanakh. Usually it's just one so that's what your used to.

Comment: What attachment?